# First time with msbuild

Tags: c#, windows, msbuild, compiler-errors

hello this is my first time with msbuild and i cant seem to get it to compile to a dll, i keep getting a

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets(490,9): e
>   rror : The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to mak
>   e sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Conf
>   iguration='Debug'  Platform='Any CPU'

error and iv searched everywhere and no solutions seem to work, iv tryed on different machines  and still the same error and i checked the environment variables and none seem to effect it also i made sure the proj file included bin\Debug\ can anyone please tell me where im going wrong? im stumped. sorry if i dont make much sense im only very new to this and learning.

Comment: Does the project build fine in Visual Studio? If so, the csproj file is an msbuild script you can copy from that works.

Comment: the build was previously made with the unity engine and a single dll file needs to be rebuild from c# scripts but i dont want to have to redo the entire thing so i have a csproj for the dll that needs to be compiled and im trying to use msbuild with that proj file, hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Your .csproj file should include `<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>`. When Visual Studio creates a project file it puts `<OutputPath>` inside a `<PropertyGroup>` element conditioned by a combination of Configuration and Platform, something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now, if you run the MSBuild from a command line with no parameters it uses `Debug` as a default value for `Configuration` and `AnyCPU` for `Platform`, just like your error message says.

So, apparently, your project file doesn't have a `<PropertyGroup>` containing an `<OutputPath>` for the Debug|AnyCPU combination.

A simple way to force it is to provide a value for the OutputPath property as a command line switch:

```
MSBuild my.csproj /p:OutputPath=bin\Debug\
```

The problem might be that usually the `<PropertyGroup>` that contains `<OutputPath>` also has more options that might be needed, so you just might need to find a valid combination of Configuration and Platform in your project file. Once you find such a combination you can set the properties accordingly using the same command line switch:

```
MSBuild my.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```